# Turning white photo to dark photo

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've taken the original photo and I was playing around in photoshop and got to amended photo. I was stupid enough to not to save the file in psd or remember how I've done it. However,I definitely remember I pressed Invert (<kbd>command</kbd> +<kbd>I</kbd> / <kbd>Control</kbd> +<kbd>I</kbd>) and my white photo turned to proportioned dark photo.

Does anybody know how? It was very simple step. It was accidental discovery. 
Would be great if someone knows the answer.

Original photo:

[image]

Amended photo: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this with `Adjustments -> Levels`

See my result and settings:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can bring up the Levels dialog with control- or command-L. In that there's a histogram in the middle and right below that there's three sliders. If you drag the middle one to the right you can get something similar to your amended image.

[image: levels dialog with mouse cursor on middle slider]